# How well do prime-started Collatz sequences cover the integers?

Tags: collatz-conjecture

Consider a liberal definition of the Collatz sequence starting from some prime number $p$:

$$
C_n(p) = \left\{ \matrix{p & n=0\\C_{n-1}(p)/2 & C_{n-1}(p) \mbox{ even}
\\ 3C_{n-1}(p)+1 & C_{n-1}(p) \mbox{ odd}}\right.
$$

That is, we are including the intermediate results rather than dividing by $2^k$ all at once.

My curiosity is about the set $\bar{C}$ of all integers that cannot be reached as $C_n(p)$ for any prime $p$. $\bar{C}$ is not empty, since no number of the form $3t$ for $t>1$ is a non-starting member of a Collatz sequence.

> Is it known whether there exists any integer $m \not\in 3\Bbb Z$ such that $\forall (n,p) : C_n(p) \neq m$?

If so, is anything known about whether there is a greatest such integer, and if there is not, then about the distribution of the members of  $\bar{C}-3\Bbb Z$?

Comment: +1. A possibly relevant and related-in-spirit question: is it known that $C(p)=\{C_n(p): n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ never has asymptotic density $1$? I don't even see why that should be easy to prove ...

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that this means in a reverse view the following. (1) Let $R(a;A) =R^{1}(a;A) = {2^A - 1 \over 3} $ *(where $A$ is chosen that $R(a;A)$ is integer)* . (2) define the iteration $R^{n}(a;A_1,A_2,...,A_n) = R( R^{n-1}(a;A_1,A_2,...,A_{n-1});A_n) $ . Then you seem to ask the question: "does exist a non-prime number $m$ such that also all numbers $R^n(m;A_1,A_2,...A_n)$ are non-prime?" . Did I get you right?

Comment: Upps., of course I meant $R(a;A)= { a \cdot 2^A-1 \over 3}$ (I forgot the $a$) in the earlier comment.

Comment: What I can tell you is that you will never find one!  Your best bet for proving this is to take any odd integer $x$ which is not a multiple of $3$ and show that the set $\{f^q(x):f(x)=4x+1\land q\in\mathbb{N_{>0}}\}$ must always contain a prime. Every odd number which is not a multiple of $3$ is a successor of such an $x$ and of every element in that set.

Comment: Do I understand correctly you are asking for some integer $m$ which is not a multiple of $3$ and is not a successor of a prime number?

Comment: I'm really curious to know what motivated this question?

Comment: I can now prove this is equivalent to the conjecture itself.  Did you know this already? A good mathematician having read Lagarias' work would be able to deduce this.

Comment: I have read Jeff's work out of curiosity (he used to be a poker buddy of mine) but did not delve deeply enough to see how his paper lets you show that the non-existence of such an $m \not\in 3\Bbb{Z}$  implies the Collatz conjecture itself. I'd love to see that proof.

Comment: Sorry Mark I only just saw your comment as you didn't ping me. I say I can prove it, I now think that was a bit strong. My thinking was the following .. if you see Lagarias' work on the 3x+1 semigroup and its inverse, the group's generators can be thought of as an infinitely long Fractran program which takes any integer as an input.  Add the rule that the program terminates upon reaching a power of $2$ and you have a turing-complete machine that stops for all inputs only if the Collatz conjecture is true. Lagarias proves the semigroup generates every integer so it generates every prime...

Comment: ...now I had some argument in mind upon writing that comment that builds upon this idea but I can't bring it to mind again now.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly the prime-started Collatz sequences completely cover the integers (excepting multiples of 3).

If we take the immediate odd predecessors $X_x$ of any odd number $x\notin3\mathbb{N}$, they are of the form $f^n(x_0)$ where $f(y)=4y+1$ and $x_0$ is their least element.

For example $X_1=\{1,5,21,85,\ldots\}$ are the immediate odd predecessors of $1$

$x_0$ takes the value of either $\frac{2x-1}{3}$ or $\frac{4x-1}{3}$ dependent upon whether $x\equiv$ $1$ or $2$ mod $3$.

The prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions states that the prime numbers are evenly distributed among the residue classes $a$ modulo $n$ with greatest common divisor $(a,n)=1$.

A good candidate for an answer may be to extend this to provide an argument that $p\in Y_x$ for some $p\in$ prime $\forall x$ which would seem likely, and this would prove there is no $m$ you seek, which is not preceded by some prime.

This theorem isn't decided for geometric progressions but Paolo Leonetti has shown it's false for the exponential-type sequences of predecessors (like $X_1$) found in the Collatz graph.

EDIT 25 MAY 2018

If you can follow the trail, following [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2705497/) Peter has searched for sequences of the above form not containing primes and identified some candidates then in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2707261/334732) Paolo Leonetti has shown that sequences starting with some $x_0$ satisfying $3x_0+1$ is square, are never prime.

The smallest example is the sequence of odd numbers which lead directly to $25$:

$X_{25}=33,133,533,\ldots$

none of which is prime.  Apart from these predecessors of squares, sieving for primes shows sequences of predecessors containing no primes are rare (none else found).

However even if the immediate odd predecessors of some number are one of the prime-free sequences like $X_{25}$, two-thirds of the numbers in that sequence still have their own sequence of predecessors and every one of those, as well as their predecessors in turn, would have to also be sequences of squares and this is clearly impossible.

It remains to prove definitively that A) ONLY the sequences satisfying $3x+1$ is a square number, are the primefree sequences of immediate odd predecessors, and B) that no sequence $X_n$ and all of its predecessors are square numbers. But this looks far from possible

Comment: Please see at my recent answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4351868/1714 which shows another class of numbers $x_0$ which have prime-free (or "composites-only") associated sequences. The first $x_0$ is $x_0=371$. The proof uses primefactorization of the first $6$ $x_k$ but does not give a more common algebraical formula for the $x_0$. So it is so far unknown, whether this class of numbers $x_0$ is finite or infinite.The linked answer gives further candidates of prime-free sequences, (the first $x_0=35$) but which are only heuristically tested up to $N=8000$ iterations being primefree.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms thanks, I saw that already.

Comment: Hi samerivertwice ...:-) Yes, I know that. I thought such a comment were good for some casual lurker. Should possibly better have mentioned at the header of my comment... P.s. Only yesterday I've found the earlier comment of Peter in 2018, where he already discovered the "covering-by-small-primes" structure, and namely the number $371$ ... didn't know this when I wrote my small draft...