# Does every sequence $4^nx_0+\frac{4^n-1}{3}$ contain a prime?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, p-adic-number-theory

> Does every sequence $4^nx_0+\dfrac{4^n-1}{3}$ contain a prime?

Fix some odd positive integer $x_0$ and define the sequence $x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots$ as follows:

$x_n=4^nx_0+\frac{4^n-1}{3}$

So for example choosing $x_0=1$ gives the sequence:

$1,5,21,85,\ldots$

And choosing $x_0=3$ gives the sequence:

$3,13,53,214,\ldots$

> Does every such sequence contain a prime number?

---

[Dirichlet's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) states that there are infinitely many primes in every arithmetic progression:

$a, a+d, a+2d,\ldots$

where $a,d$ are coprime.  But I'm unaware of similar results for other progressions.  I found [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.6307) (which is beyond me) but my rudimentary understanding suggests this is saying the result is unknown for geometric progressions.

The progressions I'm asking about are exponential in nature.  These are in fact the canonical set of linear combinations of the [Lucas Sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence) $U_1(5,4)$ and $V_1(5,4)$ over the odd integers.

Every successor $x_n:n\geq0$ is of course $\equiv 5\mod 8$ while every sequence for which $x_0\not\equiv\{1,3,7\}\mod 8$ is a subsequence of a longer sequence (with a smaller starting number), which does start with $x_0\equiv\{1,3,7\}\mod 8$.

So the set of all odd integers can be canonically indexed according to membership of the sequences starting with $x_0\equiv\{1,3,7\}\mod 8$.

I suspect these sequences have a close relationship with the kernel of the 2-adic logarithm, although I don't know a lot about that.

EDIT
So far we have found that $5$ [is the only prime](https://oeis.org/A002450) in $1,5,21,85,...$ so not every sequence has infinitely many primes.

UPDATE
Peter posted this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2707247/does-the-sequence-x-0-8-x-n1-4x-n1-contain-a-prime) for a candidate for a sequence with no primes and Paolo Leonetti has elegantly verified it has no primes, plus provided a class of such sequences which contain no primes; those for which $3x_0+1$ is a square number.

Comment: Look up [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)

Comment: Does Dirichlet's theorem have a case that covers exponentially distributed sequences?

Comment: @stevengregory thanks. I was aware of that... And can see it's related. But does it decide this? These sequences are neither arithmetic not geometric progressions.

Comment: @Valborg precisely

Comment: For a fixed n, they are indeed arithmetic progressions.

Comment: @stevengregory But that doesn't stop some fixed $x$ from dodging all primes, at least not obviously.

Comment: In the example, $1,5,21,85\dots,$ what is $x$?  In particular, how do you get $1$?

Comment: @saulspatz I believe that had n=0 and x=1

Comment: Then the question should say $n=0,1,2,\dots$ instead of $n=1,2,3,\dots$

Comment: If we are going to exclude $n=0$, it would appear that $x=5$ is a great candidate to hunt for a prime free sequence. If we include $n=0$, then try $x=21$.

Comment: @saulspatz you're right about the possibility of starting that sequence at 0 but the subsequence i give starting at 1 is also such a sequence. In fact for every sequence you can start at any point along it and that is also such a sequence so I am actually asking if every sequence has infinitely many primes. Although the weaker result that we can start as low as possible, i.e. at some number $\equiv 1,3,7\mod 8$ and always find at least one prime would be something.

Comment: $4^{72}\cdot 8+\frac{4^{72}-1}{3}$ is a Fermat-pseudoprime to bases $3$ and $5$ , but composite. $x_0=8$ is a hard case as well.

Comment: @Peter I was only considering odd numbers and yes, sequences including $x_0$. If i understand correctly you mean the sequence $x_0\ldots=33,133,533,\ldots$ is a hard case?

Comment: @Peter if you allow even $x_0$, every $x_1$ is $\in \{1,3,7\}\mod 8$ anyway so it makes no odds, they're the same sequences

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75052/discussion-between-peter-and-producer-of-bs).

Answer (score 2):

Aside of the nice solution provided in the other thread, which uses the algebraic factorization of the original formula when $3 x_0+1$ is a square, I have found a list of further solutions for $x_0$ such that the associated sequence contains no primes/only composites.
The sequences from $$x_0 \in \{371,495,775,1671,2171,3211,3955,4215,4655,4711,... \} \\ 
\text{have as well no prime entries.} \hspace{160pt} $$

This can easily be proved by looking at the small primefactors $p \in \{3,5,7,13\}$ : their cyclical occurences in the respective iteration sequence $S(x_0)$ have lengthes $\text{cyclen}(x_0,p) \in \{2,3,6\}$ and cover completely the $6$ leading entries of their sequence. Due to cyclicity each entry of the sequences $ \gt 13$ cannot be prime.

Example for $x_0=371$:

```
 N     primefact's x_N   Covering periodically
                          6 of 6 residueclasses
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
[ 0           "7.53"]       __7_        == 371
[ 1       "3^3.5.11"]       35__        == 4*371+1
[ 2         "13.457"]       ___1        == 4*(4*371+1)+1 
[ 3       "5.7^2.97"]       _57_  
[ 4        "3.31687"]       3___
[ 5      "5.113.673"]       _5__
- - - - - - - - - - - 
[ 6     "7.11.19753"]       __7_
[ 7    "3.5^2.81119"]       35__
[ 8    "13.293.6389"]       ___1
[ 9  "5.7.1427.1949"]       _57_
[10 "3^2.1423.30403"]       3___
[11  "5.11.28317907"]       _5__
- - - - - - - - - - - - 
 ... ... ... ...  ...
```

Unfortunately I didn't find any further algebraical expression of this phenomenon, like the style of the one that has already been given with the $3x_0+1 \text{ -is-square}$ class of solutions.

Moreover there might be some further characteristics in/by the following list of $x_0$. The list has been created by checking the computing time up to $1000$ iterates, where the ones with $0$ *msecs* have been the suspect ones, and which gave the examples of the above mentioned covering-primefactors-solutions:
$$ \quad \text{covering } \; \mid \; \text{ heuristics}  \phantom{sequence beginning at $35$ has a prime (see update at bottom)} \\
\small \begin{array} {rrr||rrr} 
 x_0 & \# & \text{msecs}& x_0 & \# & \text{msecs}\\ \hline
 371 & 0 & 0 & 35 & 0 & 125  & \text{sequence beginning at $35$ has a prime (see update at bottom)}\\ 
 495 & 0 & 0 & 603 & 0 & 171 \\ 
 775 & 0 & 0 & 1195 & 0 & 282 \\ 
 1671 & 0 & 0 & 1335 & 0 & 218 \\ 
 2171 & 0 & 0 & 1379 & 0 & 266 \\ 
 3211 & 0 & 0 & 1611 & 0 & 31 \\ 
 3955 & 0 & 0 & 1751 & 0 & 141 \\ 
 4215 & 0 & 0 & 2755 & 0 & 172 \\ 
 4655 & 0 & 0 & 2775 & 0 & 234 \\ 
 4711 & 0 & 0 & 2791 & 0 & 156 \\ 
 4971 & 0 & 15 & 3179 & 0 & 250 \\ 
 5195 & 0 & 0 & 3379 & 0 & 140 \\ 
 5831 & 0 & 16 & 4011 & 0 & 204 \\ 
 5955 & 0 & 0 & 4235 & 0 & 94 \\ 
 6235 & 0 & 0 & 5395 & 0 & 141 \\ 
 7131 & 0 & 0 & 5495 & 0 & 47 \\ 
 7631 & 0 & 0 & 5751 & 0 & 93 \\ 
 8671 & 0 & 0 & 5975 & 0 & 125 \\ 
 9415 & 0 & 0 & 6215 & 0 & 93 \\ 
 9675 & 0 & 0 & 6571 & 0 & 141 \\ 
 10115 & 0 & 0 & 6671 & 0 & 140 \\ 
 10171 & 0 & 0 & 6875 & 0 & 126 \\ 
 10431 & 0 & 0 & 7551 & 0 & 171 \\ 
 10655 & 0 & 0 & 7775 & 0 & 203 \\ 
 ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...
 \end{array}$$
where "#" denotes the number of primes found up to tested  iterations.

The timings were measured for up to $N=1000$ iterations
(using primecertifying `isprime()` in `Pari/GP vers. 2.14, 64 bit`.

*updated table*:The column headed with "covering" contains that cases of $x_0$ for which the **covering** by the small primes occurs, so this gives ***proven non-prime sequences***, the column headed with "heuristics" contains the cases, where the primecertification showed all iterates being composite but only up to $N=1000$ (for up to $N=8000$ iterations I used the `ispseudoprime()` test).

For instance, $x_0=35$ needs further work to discern whether the iterations sequence has primes or not; there have been a couple of prime-canditates by a fast (pseudo)prime-test for $N>1000$ but which were certificated to be composite with the more intense `isprime()`-function. The time to do this increases excessively and unpredictable, so I stopped testing of $x_N$ at $N=2000$.

***update 3.feb.2022*** The sequence beginning at $x_0=35$ seems to contain a prime at $(106 \cdot 4^{4553}-1)/3$ as certified by the [prime-tester of Dario Alpern](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM). The number $x_{4553}$ has $2743$ digits and leading and trailing digits $5 337343 165620  \ldots 969933 010261$

Comment: see a pdf-version in https://go.helms-net.de/math/divers/mse/PrimesInSyracuseTree.pdf

Comment: Nice work.    