# Are the prime-free sequences $x_{n+1}=4x_n+1$ of odd numbers in bijection with the square numbers greater than $16$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, square-numbers, collatz-conjecture

> Are the prime-free sequences $x_{n+1}=4x_n+1$ of odd numbers in bijection with the even square numbers greater than $16$?

Specifically:

Consider only sequences of odd, positive integers, plus zero.

$x_{n+1}=4x_n+1$ is [prime free](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2707261/334732) if $3x_0+1$ is square.

But is it prime-free *only* if $3x_0+1$ is square?

We have the trivial exceptions $0,1,5$ which give squares $1,4,16$; but above that?

---

A little background / what I know so far... and this is vague and possibly not that helpful :(

1. These sequences are linear combinations of the Lucas sequences:

$a\cdot U_n(5,4)+b\cdot V_n(5,4)$

where $a,b$ take the form:

$a=\frac{3x_0+2}{2}, b=\frac{x_0}{2}$

2. The sequences can be canonically indexed by $x_0\equiv\{1,3,7\}\mod 8$

i.e. every sequence satisfying $x_0\equiv 5\mod 8$ is a subsequence of one of these.

3. I think it's relevant that $3x_0+1$ is always even, and all even squares are of course equivalent mod $4$.

A huge wealth of important results exists into [primitive primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael%27s_theorem) in sequences such as these

4. The Collatz conjecture says the orbits of the Collatz function $(3x+1)\lvert3x+1\rvert_2$ totally order these sequences.
5. I keep suspecting a relationship between the Collatz graph and the kernel of the 2-adic logarithm. Not sure if there's anything in that.

Comment: For $x_0=306$ , there always seems to be a small factor. The generating function is $$\frac{919\cdot 4^n-1}{3}$$ in this case.

Comment: The primes upto $13$ seem to be a "covering set"

Comment: @Peter that's interesting again because that sequence starts $x_0=1225$ (in the odd numbers) which is $7^2\times5^2$.  Also $13$ is potentially of slight interest because $12^2$ is the sole exception to Carmichael's theorem which is important in this field.

Comment: @Peter are you able to describe more precisely what you mean about the covering set?

Comment: The set covers all cases (See also my answer)

Comment: $x_0=371$ has a "covering set" as well , quite similar to that of $x_0=306$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sequence $$\frac{919\cdot 4^n-1}{3}$$ is primefree because the number $919\cdot 4^n-1$

- is divisble by $9$ if $n=3k$
- is divisble by $5$ if $n=2k+1$
- is diviyble by $7$ if $n=3k+1$
- is divisble by $13$ if $n=6k+2$

Hence, beginning with $x_0=306$ , we have another prime-free sequence.

Comment: A list of starting numbers which produce prime-free iteration-sequences has been shown in my answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4351868/1714 , using the here mentioned "covering"-argument. However I do not know yet, whether this list is finite or infinite. Moreover, I provided related list, but which seems to not fall into this class of initial values, but are primefree up to iterations $N=8000$. For the latter list no algebraical or algorithmical property has been found so far indicating primeness of the sequences, or indicating special properties of the initial values.