# Collatz proven for primes = proven for all integers?

Tags: reference-request, collatz-conjecture

I recently saw a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5L1J2eljjdg) stating that if the Collatz conjecture was proven for prime numbers, it was proven for all numbers.
That's the first time I see this and I can't find any references with the classical JFGI.

It says something like this ($a$, $b$, $n$ are odd integers):

$\sigma_p(n)$ is the Collatz trajectory ($p$ steps applied to $n$)
and for a fixed function $f(b)$ not provided you have:

$\sigma_p(an+b)=a\cdot\sigma_p(n)+f^p(b)$

and specially for odd prime factorization:

$\sigma_p(an)=a\cdot\sigma_p(n)+f^p(0)$

Apparently, it can be shown that if $\sigma(n)<n$ than $\sigma(an)<an$ and it suffice to show for all prime $n$ since a **finite stopping time for primes implies a finite stopping time for all its composite**

I tried on some numbers (e.g., $85=5\cdot 17$) but couldn't figure it out.

> Is there a paper on this subject? The video seems to talk about a $15$ page proof.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132930/discussion-on-question-by-user489810-collatz-proven-for-primes-proven-for-all).

Comment: It looks like we expect every integer (besides multiples of $3$) to show up somewhere in the orbit of a sequence that starts at a prime number. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2324448/how-well-do-prime-started-collatz-sequences-cover-the-integers) for instance. Then knowing the collatz conjecture for primes would give us the collatz conjecture for all non-multiples-of-$3$. But since any multiple of $3$ eventually transitions into a non-multiple-of-$3$ (exercise) we get the claim for all numbers.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire ok changed my comment to an answer then.

Comment: @user489810 I made a new addition to my post. I show that $\sigma_p\left( n\right) \lt n \nRightarrow \sigma_q\left( an\right) \lt an$

Answer (score 5):

**NEW SECTION ON THE BOTTOM**

I think it is highly likely that there is no paper showing that if the collatz conjecture is true for primes it is true for all numbers.

In the original post, it was claimed that it can be shown that $\sigma\left( n\right) \lt n \implies \sigma\left( an\right) \lt an$

( I'm assuming the implication is $\sigma_p\left( n\right) \lt n \implies \sigma_p\left( an\right) \lt an \quad$ and not $\sigma_p\left( n\right) \lt n \implies \sigma_q\left( an\right) \lt an$ )

This implication is not only false for specific cases, it is also false for whole families of cases.

If $n$ is of the form $4b+1$ and $a$ is of the form $4c+3$ then $\sigma_3\left( n\right) \lt n$ but $\sigma_3\left( an\right) \gt an$

On top of that, the factorization of a number doesn't help that much in determining the trajectory of the number in collatz conjecture. There are three operators that are used in the conjecture (/2,*3,+1). The /2 and the *3 operators change the factorization of the number by adding or subtracting a single prime factor. The +1 operator however changes the factorization of the number in unpredictable ways. There are two things that you can conclude after the +1. The first is that since the number was odd before the +1 it will be even after the +1. The second is that since two consecutive numbers don't share any factors, the number before +1 will have a different set of factors from the number after +1. After those two things any information about the factorization of the numbers, in general, is really hard to come by. This is what makes collatz conjecture so difficult, to begin with. The idea that you can gain information about the trajectory of multiples of primes by learning about the trajectory of prime values just doesn't make sense.

$31$ takes $106$ steps to reach $1$, but $31*11$ takes $11$ steps to reach $1$

$3$ takes $7$ steps to reach $1$, but $3*9$ takes $111$ steps to reach $1$

$17$ takes $12$ steps to reach $1$, but $17*40$ takes $12$ steps to reach $1$

So in the first case multiplying a prime by a number decreased the number of steps by a large margin. In the second case multiplying a prime by a number increased the number of steps by a large margin. In the third case multiplying a prime by a number kept the number of steps the same.

**Edit**: The OP has said in comments that the person in the video said that the function is an affine function. (Which I probably should have figured out beforehand). This means that $f$ is of the form $ f(x) = mx+n$ where $m,n\in \Bbb{R}$. $m,n\in \Bbb{R}$ for general affine equations. In this case, $m,n\in \Bbb{Q}$ because Rational numbers are closed under the four basic operators ($+,-,*,/$).

The OP mentioned in the original post that one of the equations used in the video is:

$\sigma_p(an)=a\cdot\sigma_p(n)+f^p(0)$

This means that $f^p(0)$ is just a constant. One thing I realized is that $\sigma_p(an)$ and $\sigma_p(n)$ are discordant. Not only because one is by itself and one is multiplied by $a$ but they don't perform the same operations from step to step. One may do the odd operation $(*3+1)$ while the other may do the even step $(/2)$. This means that $f^p(0)$ is just the correction term needed to make the equation equal. This is why $f$ isn't defined. It is almost impossible to know what $f^p(0)$ will be without calculating $\sigma_p(an)$ and $\sigma_p(n)$ then solving for $f^p(0)$. We can see how this would work by using one of the examples above. Let $n=31$ and $a=11$.

We start with $\sigma_0(11*31)=11\cdot\sigma_0(31)+f^0(0)$. This means we haven't applied any steps so $f^0(0)=0$ and the equation is just $341=341$. Next,

$\sigma_1(11*31)=11\cdot\sigma_1(31)+f^1(0)$

$\sigma_1(11*31)=1024$, $\quad\sigma_1(31)=94$

both sigmas apply an odd step. Multiplying by three does the same thing to both sides but, adding $1$ to both sides does not. On the left side, one is added but the one on the right is multiplied by 11 so this adds $11$. This means $f^1(0)=-10$ Next,

$\sigma_2(11*31)=11\cdot\sigma_2(31)+f^2(0)$

Both sigmas apply an even step so both sides are divided by $2$ including the $f^1(0)$. So $\sigma_2(11*31)=512,\quad\sigma_2(31)=47,\quad f^2(0)=-5$. Next,

$\sigma_3(11*31)=11\cdot\sigma_3(31)+f^3(0)$

The left sigma applies an even step and the right sigma applies an odd step so $\sigma_3(11*31)=256,\quad\sigma_3(31)=142,\quad \bf{f^3(0)=-1306}$. Next,

$\sigma_4(11*31)=11\cdot\sigma_4(31)+f^4(0)$

$\sigma_4(11*31)=128,\quad\sigma_4(31)=71,\quad f^4(0)=-653$

$\sigma_5(11*31)=11\cdot\sigma_5(31)+f^5(0)$

$\sigma_5(11*31)=64,\quad\sigma_5(31)=214,\quad f^5(0)=-2290$

If $f$ is just a post-hoc correction term it is useless. If $f$ isn't just a post-hoc correction it needs a far more extensive explanation by the person in the video.

**EDIT 2:**

Earlier in this post, I showed that $\sigma_p\left( n\right) \lt n \nRightarrow \sigma_p\left( an\right) \lt an$. What I want to show here is for non-trival pairs of $p$ and $q\quad \sigma_p\left( n\right) \lt n \nRightarrow \sigma_q\left( an\right) \lt an$.

The trivial case of the implication $\sigma_1\left( n\right) \lt n \implies \sigma_1\left( an\right) \lt an$ is true. $\sigma_1\left( n\right) \lt n$ implies that $n$ is even. Any integer multiplied by an even number is even therefore $an$ is also even. So after this paragraph $a$ and $n$ are odd.

In order to show that the implication is false for non-trivial $p$,$q$ pairs I will use Euler’s theorem and an expansion property of a specific type of number ($x^{yz}-1$) where $x,y,z\in\Bbb{N}\space|\space x,y,z>1$. Euler’s theorem states that if $r,s \in \Bbb{N}\space|\space gcd(r,s)=1$ then $s\space |\space r^{\phi\left(s\right)}-1$ Where $\phi()$ is the Euler totient function. The expansion property is $x^{yz}-1=(x^y-1)(x^{y(z-1)}+x^{y(z-2)}+x^{y(z-3)}+…+x^{3y}+x^{2y}+x^y+1)$ this implies $(x^y-1)|(x^{yz}-1)$

After $2\phi(n)$ collatz steps the expression $2^{\phi(n)}-1$ turns into $3^{\phi(n)}-1$ without going lower than $2^{\phi(n)}-1$. This means that $\sigma_{2\phi(n)}\left( 2^{\phi(n)}-1\right) \gt 2^{\phi(n)}-1$. From Euler’s theorem  $n|2^{\phi(n)}-1$. Let $k\in\Bbb{N}$. From the expansion property $(2^{\phi(n)}-1)|(2^{k\phi(n)}-1)$.  Let $an=(2^{k\phi(n)}-1)$. The expression $2^{k\phi(n)}-1$ is also divisible by $n$ because it contains all factors of $(2^{\phi(n)}-1)$.  The expression $2^{k\phi(n)}-1$ takes $2k\phi(n)$ collatz steps to turn into $3^{k\phi(n)}-1$  without going lower than $2^{k\phi(n)}-1$. $k$ can be arbitrarily large this means that with a given $n$  and $q\space \exists\space  a,k\space|\space \sigma_q\left( an\right) \gt an$.

For example let’s pick $n=77$ and $q=1000$. $77$ takes three steps to become less than itself. So $\sigma_3\left( 77\right) \lt 77$. In order to make the implication false we need $2k\phi(n)>q\rightarrow k\ge 9$. We let $an=2^{k\phi(n)}-1=2^{540}-1$. This means $\sigma_3\left( 77\right) \lt 77 \nRightarrow \sigma_{1000}\left( 2^{540}-1\right) \lt 2^{540}-1$

$\mathbf{\sigma_p\left( n\right) \lt n \nRightarrow \sigma_q\left( an\right) \lt an}$

Comment: The guy seemed legit (some guest professor on a math channel for math students), but I am also skeptical. I also saw the issues with my tests $\sigma_p$ to $\sigma_p$ instead of $\sigma_p$ to $\sigma_r$, but I kept the formulas from the video as they were shown. And since I don't know what $f(b)$ is, I can't tell if the number of steps is relevant or not in the proof. But if it is not, you are right, the "+1" needs to be fully understood which I highly doubt.

Comment: @user489810 I tried looking at the video, but I don't speak French. If someone or some program could translate the video I think I could evaluate if his claims were true or not

Comment: He is presenting the State of the art of the collatz
24:30 "There is a property that says: if it work for prime numbers, it works for all numbers"
25:00 "If for all n in P (primes) Pn true (converge to 1), then for all n in N, Pn also true
25:38 "Demonstration is very complicated, and takes around 15 pages. I will not do it here. I will only put the plan. If a,b odd...."
26:20 "f is a affine function"
26:55 "Then I can generalize. If a,b odd, ..."
27:40 "What it means is that for any number of iteration of my linear combination, I stay on a linear linear combination"

Comment: Then he shows the case where b is 0 and explain the prime factorization (a*n), and a bit of what I put above. Then talk about the special case of 2 and then the odd cases

Comment: @user489810 one of the things you just said was actually quite useful I'm going to make an edit to my answer stay tuned

Comment: @user489810 I just edited my post check it out

Comment: Thanks. That's indeed $f$ I was curious about (my comment about it was moved to a chat).

Comment: Ok, I don't have a link to that paper (and still don't know if it really exists), but thank you for your time.

Comment: @user489810 I have two other ideas you can try the first is to comment on the video and ask for the paper. Second, if the professor's name is mentioned you can email him ask for the paper

Comment: Thanks. I saw someone else trying to ask with no response. And I searched his name in comments or audio of this video and 1 other he made, but there is none

Comment: Thanks :). I am really wondering what was in that paper he mentioned.....

Answer (score 0):

To prove this, you’d likely show “for any n >= 2, the collatz sequence leads to an integer < n, or to a prime.”

This is most likely true, but very hard to prove, because the sequence is quite chaotic. That’s the same as the original problem, which is most likely true, but very hard to prove, because the sequence is quite chaotic.

If someone had a proof for this conjecture that could be very insightful. I’d be surprised.

Comment: Yes, you would still need to prove it for primes the same way as the original. I would also be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

I think every 5-rough integer is preceded by some prime number - I don't know a proof of this but the result claimed in the question does follows from it, if true. An argument in favour of this goes: If you take any 5-rough composite number and think how much freedom you have to find a prime that precedes it, you can pick from infinitely many Lucas Sequences.

These Lucas sequences contain no prime only under very limited circimstances, so every number is almost certainly preceded by some prime, which is precisely the same statement you're asking about.

You can see some rare cases in which whole classes of predecessors of some number are prime-free here: [Does the sequence $x_0=8$ , $x_{n+1}=4x_n+1$ contain a prime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2707247/) and in the questions linked to that.  None of these comes close to showing some infinite sequence of composite numbers.